# Передача обобщенного типа в другой метод/функцию

Tags: c#, generics

Вызываю из обобщенной функции другую функцию, передавая при этом туда обобщенный тип. Среда ругается на преобразование из типа T в тип Sale. Как сделать, чтобы можно было из списка передавать любой класс(например, и category и sale)?

```
public bool IsValid(Category category)
        {
            if (category == null)
            {
                ErrorText = "Не указано поле 'Категория'";
                return false;
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(category.Name))
            {
                ErrorText = Properties.Resources.StringValidateError + $" Категория ID:{category.Id}";
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
public bool IsValid(Sale sale)
{
    if(sale == null)
    {
        ErrorText = "Не указано поле 'Продажа'";
        return false;
    }
    if(sale.Amount < 0)
    {
        ErrorText = Properties.Resources.AmountValidateError + $", Продавец: {sale.EmployeeId}, Товар: {sale.ProductId}";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public bool IsValid<T>(IEnumerable<T> listDTO)
{
    foreach(T ob in listDTO)
    {
        if (!IsValid(ob))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно создать интерфейс `IValidatable` (как подсказали в предыдущем ответе) и в нём сделать метод `IsValid`. От него унаследовать классы `Sale`, `Category`. В каждом из них сделать метод `IsValid()`. И тогда можно определить код обобщённого `IsValid` вот таким образом:

```
interface IValidatable
{
    bool IsValid();
}

public class Sale : IValidatable
{
    ...
    public bool IsValid()
    {
       // Здесь логика валидации для Sale
    }
}

//Аналогичным образом сделать для Category и для всех други классов, которые будут
//валидироваться

public bool IsValid<T>(IEnumerable<T> listDTO) where T : IValidatable
{
    foreach(T ob in listDTO)
    {
       if (!ob.IsValid())
          return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

В таком случае, будет вызываться метод `IsValid` каждого объекта, который хранится в этой коллекции.

Comment: Мне кажется `T` тут вообще не нужен, вместо него можно везде сразу написать `IValidatable`

Comment: @CrazyElf да, согласен. Обобщёный тип можно будет добавить, если будут ограничения ещё на какие-либо интерфейсы. В данном случае будет достаточно IValidatable

Comment: Мне кажется, добавлять методы, работающие с интерфейсом (а метод автора подразумевает это) в модель данных - не очень хорошая идея.

Comment: Согласен. Имеет смысл создать валидатор и там определять методы валидации для каждой валидируемой сущности. В таком случае нужно будет также немного доработать обобщённый `IsValid` метод

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (!IsValid(ob as Sale) && !IsValid(ob as Category))
        return false;
```

Comment: Если я добавлю класс Category и захочу обработать список с экземплярами этого класса, как мне сделать это не переписывая вторую функцию?

Comment: @ЛевЧуприн Мне плохо видно, что делается у Вас в голове и на экране. Дополнительный код добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Смешно) Но если у меня таких классов и функций для каждого класса 50шт?

Comment: @Hellowar Заведите интерфейс `IValidatable` и добавьте ограничение `where T : IValidatable`.

Comment: Добавил, но дальше ничего. Мы передаем объект IValidatable в другую функцию IsValid и как бы все сводится к написанию функционала в одной функции.

Comment: @Hellowar Я не понял, что Вы хотели сказать.